# Actionbar back button functionality not changing

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have a Fragment A from which another Fragment B is loaded.In Fragment A actionbar I have a hamburger menu and when I move to Fragment B, it should be changed to back menu button. When back button is loaded, the functionality of the menu should be changed from hamburger menu which loads the drawer layout, to the back button menu which loads the previous Fragement IE. Fragment B. I am able to change the icon of the menu from hamburger to back button, but I am not able to change the functionality of the icon when back button is loaded.

I am changing the button in action bar in Fragment B by the following code

```
MainActivity.mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

Can any body please help me by suggesting a way to change the functionality of the menu button when Fragment B is loaded and to reset the icon and functionality of back button to Hamburger menu, navigated back to Fragment A

Comment: Have you try drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    drawerToggle.syncState();
                    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_white);
                }
            });

Comment: And you can check Fragment is in stack then remove like that  getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

Answer (score 0):

you can set listener for navigation click

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //add here the action you need
                //example call on back pressed of activity or call 
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                onBackPressed(); 

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When icon is changed use `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` if the current icon is Back Button.

And use the following logic in `NavigationOnClickListener`

```
if(condition for changing the icon) //for eg : check for current fragment is home or not
{ 
   getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
   mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}
```

Hope this may work fine for you. Happy Coding